# What is the correct way to show a Currency Symbol or Text across all prices shown in the store, cart and checkout?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, store-view, checkout-page, currency-symbol

**Show a Currency Symbol or Text across all prices**

> For example to show NZD after each $XXX.YY so it would display as
>   $XXX.YY NZD

This is to be shown on Product pages, cart, checkout.

Is there a single setting for this, or do we have to tediously make a bunch of plugin interceptors and template edits (I have done just that in the past)?

I feel that this sort of thing should just be a built in feature of Magento 2 and I want to avoid re-inventing the wheel if there is a correct way to do this.

Magento 2.3+

Kind regards,
Liam

Edit: If you are implementing something like this for a Bank to let you use them with another payment gateway e.g. they give a Merchant ID to the third party gateway. Just ask if you can simply put a line of text on the order summary stating "All prices are in NZD." So much easier....

Comment: Do you want to change the currency symbol across whole website?

Comment: Yes, currency is already NZD but the bank wants to see " NZD" symbol after the prices as part of their requirements checklist to use their API for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url, I already share my answer here :

[currency format in mini cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278284/currency-format-in-mini-cart/278311#278311)

Comment: Not quite what I am after.

Create a plugin \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format afterPriceFormat
Modify the $result as needed?

But want to append some text string after the price.
And also in the other places like product page, cart, viewing previous orders.

Seems like many places must be either edited template or a plugin rather tedious :( was hoping for a simple elegant way that I had not realized on.